# bootstrap glyphicons are not working in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, glyphicons, gulp-sass

I made a website using a yeoman-generator webapp,bootstrap and sass. the site is built and everything was working fine but when i tried to make the site into a WordPress theme the glyphicons stopped showing.So i checked and the **src path to the glyphicons were wrong**. *the path had everything correct but it left out the theme's name (apple)*.

ex:-

correct = C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\apple\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

wrong = C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Answer (score 0):

Don't change Bootstrap file location, it's not a good practice. Keep all the Bootstrap's files inside the bootstrap folder and just include the CSS and JS file from there in your page.

You can checkout this page for more info - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-get-started.php

Comment: thank you alex for answering. i didn't change bootstrap's file location, its sill in the root directory or where my index.php is. The bootstrap style and my own style is integrated into one style-sheet. My styles are written after the bootstrap's styles. the JavaScript files are in a folder called "scripts" and the fonts are in a folder called fonts , all of which is in the root directory.

Comment: Hi Joe have you checked Bootstrap CSS file is correctly included in your page or not. Also make sure Bootstrap's fonts folder exists at the location where the Bootstrap's css folder exist. Nothing more is required.

Comment: hi Alex,
Yes bootstrap is working fine, and the fonts folder is in the same folder as bootstrap's css. only the glyphicons are not showing with bootstraps default glyphicons path "url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) " so i added " url(../apple/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) " like wise for .ttf , .woff , .svg , .eot . 
("apple" is my theme's name)

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons are not part of Bootstrap 4 anymore.
Because UnderStrap based on Bootstrap 4 they were removed too.

```
use this cdn :
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```